# Change string to date and joining on date range in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below two tables:

[image]

[image]

~ What I am looking to do: I want to append the Price from Table 2 (t2) to Table 1 (t1), by joining on Quantity and YYYY_MM. Each t2.price was active in a certain time range (t2.Price_Active_Date_From and t2.Price_Active_Date_To), and the t1.Order_YYYYMM should fall within this range. Year 9999 indicates that the price has no end date yet, and is therefore still active. I also want to find which price was active 1 year prior to the order date

So the result should look like:

[image]

What I have tried below so far, which works to get the Price_Active_At_Order, but  I am not sure how to get Price_Active_PY when my date values are strings:

```
select distinct
t1.Product_NR,
t1.Customer,
t1.Quantity,
t2.Price as Price_Active_At_Order,
t1.Order_YYYYMM as Order_Date

from Table_1 t1
join Table_2 t2 on t1.Product_NR = t2.Product_NR
                and t1.Quantity = t2.Quantity
                and t1.Order_YYYYMM between t2.Price_Active_Date_From and t2.Price_Active_Date_To
```

Comment: What's that WHERE clause meant to be doing? You try parsing a string to a date, but then do nothing with it, is there meant to be a comparison? Why do you think you need to convert the strings to dates, provided they're all in that format, just compare the strings? What exactly is your question? You haven't said the results are wrong, or if there is an error message, or anything. Please read this: [How to do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks as mentioned a couple of times below as well, the WHERE seems not to be useful so I exclude it now in my query. It does not completely work still, when Price_Active_Date_To = '999912'. It seems to pick a random Order_Date in this situation. I edited my question to include this comment

Comment: Please read the link I provided, and pay close attention to instructions regard Minimal Viable Example. When I test similar code with the value 999912 it works fine, so create a test data set, including table definitions, that demonstrates your problem case. We can then copy and run your code to replicate your problem, for example on it seems to work here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=119e89301060442d7a1e06ce70a3020d

Comment: It also appears to work with (the insanely bad idea) using strings for dates; https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6cdefeda9854a67229b37dd7383158a0 (Your problem can't be replicated with your example data and code)

Comment: Thanks, it seems there was an error still in my query because now it works - apologies for the misunderstanding. I added another piece to my question that I missed to ask, would be great if you can give it a look please

Comment: That's a materially different question that invalidates the answers already present, please do not do that. Instead, please open a new question and I'll be happy to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to point out:

- Line 6 : `te.Order_YYYYMM as Order_Date` change to `t1.Order_YYYYMM as Order_Date`
- Line 13,14,15 : `where` clause  is incomplete and unnecessary, remove it

Your code should work fine with the changes above.

```
select distinct
t1.Product_NR,
t1.Customer,
t1.Quantity,
t2.Price as Price_Active_At_Order,
t1.Order_YYYYMM as Order_Date

from Table_1 t1
join Table_2 t2 on t1.Product_NR = t2.Product_NR
                and t1.Quantity = t2.Quantity
                and t1.Order_YYYYMM between t2.Price_Active_Date_From and t2.Price_Active_Date_To
```

Comment: Thanks I tried your suggestion, which works for all BUT for Price_Active_Date_To '999912'. It seems to pick a random Order_Date in this situation. 
I edited my question to include this comment

Comment: @Es-Dot, youre welcome, from the sample data and output you provided, it works fine. Maybe you should add / change your sample data to show the problem

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. I'm guessing I made a mistake still in my query because now it works. so apologies for that. I added another piece to my question, would you know how to pull the price that was active 1 year prior to the order date? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a single row in `table2` that can supply the complete quantity corresponding to a `table1` row at the minimum price then, from Oracle 12, you can use a `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT price,
                price_active_date_from,
                price_active_date_to
         FROM   table2 t2
         WHERE  t1.product_nr = t2.product_nr
         AND    t1.quantity   <= t2.quantity
         AND    t1.order_yyyymm BETWEEN t2.price_active_date_from
                                    AND t2.price_active_date_to
         ORDER BY t2.price ASC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) t2
       ON (1 = 1)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (product_nr, customer, quantity, order_yyyymm) AS
SELECT 10023, 'X', 20, 202104 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10023, 'Y', 10, 202203 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10334, 'X',  1, 202204 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (product_nr, quantity, price, price_active_date_from, price_active_date_to) AS
SELECT 10023,   1, 100, 202101, 999912 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10023,  10,  80, 201605, 202012 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10023,  10, 120, 202101, 202205 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10023,  20, 250, 202101, 999912 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10023, 100, 400, 202101, 202111 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10334,   1,  25, 202101, 202111 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10334,   1,  30, 202112, 202205 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PRODUCT_NR | CUSTOMER | QUANTITY | ORDER_YYYYMM | PRICE | PRICE_ACTIVE_DATE_FROM | PRICE_ACTIVE_DATE_TO |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 10023 | X | 20 | 202104 | 250 | 202101 | 999912 |
> | 10023 | Y | 10 | 202203 | 120 | 202101 | 202205 |
> | 10334 | X | 1 | 202204 | 30 | 202112 | 202205 |

---

If you want to find the row in `table2` that can supply the quantity from the cumulative quantities between that row and the preceding rows within the date range ordered by ascending price then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT price,
                price_active_date_from,
                price_active_date_to
         FROM   (
           SELECT price,
                  price_active_date_from,
                  price_active_date_to,
                  SUM(quantity) OVER (ORDER BY price ASC) AS quantity
           FROM   table2 t2
           WHERE  t1.product_nr = t2.product_nr
           AND    t1.order_yyyymm BETWEEN t2.price_active_date_from
                                      AND t2.price_active_date_to
         ) t2
         WHERE  t1.quantity   <= t2.quantity
         ORDER BY t2.price ASC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       ) t2
       ON (1 = 1)
```

Which, for the sample data, has the same output.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=67d399feb36548b8a86838cc3f9a75b7)*